# Using Codeigniter Routing and .htaccess URL rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I wanted to understand Codeigniter URL Routing and .htaccess URL Rewriting.
Are both same?

Basically, I want to hide my ID which is passed to the controller. Do I want to understand how can I use any of them to do so?

Also is it possible that I can just show my domain and the folder name and hide another part of URL

**Eg.**

`www.example.com/distributor/tenant/info/1`

`www.example.com/distributor`

So can I hide my controller and id using .htaccess

My Current .htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /bizcloudds/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Can this same thing be done with Codeigniter Routes?

I saw something like this on codeigniter's documentation on `Routes` :

```
$route['blog/joe'] = 'blogs/users/34';
```

But I don't understand how will I get `34` i.e ID of the record in my routes files?

I have very little knowledge of .htaccess and Codeigniter Routes, So please explain.

Comment: _“Basically, I want to hide my ID which is passed to the controller”_ – that is of course impossible. If the client requests just `/distributor`, then there is _no way_ for the server to relate that to any specific id. You could use POST for all your requests, so that the user would not directly _see_ the ID value you are passing - but if you think that would make your application a single bit “safer”, then you would wrong as could be already.

Comment: _“Also is it possible that I can just show my domain and the folder name and hide another part of URL”_ – why would you even want to do that? It will keep people from bookmarking specific pieces of content, it will hinder search engines from indexing individual pieces of content ... This is the type of question that usually gets asked by people who, to put it bluntly, have little to no idea how the internet works ...

Comment: They are not the same. Routes are used to change CI's standard segment-based approach to URLs - [Documentation Here.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)  Consider using session data to pass the ID.

Comment: Use post method. so it will be possible to solve your probelm

Comment: @FairyDancer post method is an option but i dont want to go with that because i dont want multiple forms in a single page.

Comment: @CBroe Can i do something like encrypted ID ? just wondering usually i see on websites at back they have some random string basically not human readable, so is there any way i can do that ? Or it is totally something different than this

Comment: Yes, many sites like f.e. URL shorteners use a system of “cryptic” IDs, mainly so that people won’t be able to guess the ID of other items by simply in- or decrementing parts of the ID. This usually means some sort of hashing algorithm gets used to translate normal, numeric database IDs into such outside identifiers.

Comment: Okay thanks i can try that for my case, but i don't want to use any third party apps for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using post method you can find solution for your question. For example

```
<form action="page_url" method="POST">
<input name="id" value="16" type="hidden">
<input type="submit" value="Show Details">
</form>
```

Hope you understand. If you need more guidance on this, I'm happy to help you out.

Comment: Thanks i have this in option, but i have many pages where i have lists, clicking on them sends id to controller, so for all thoses list pages i will have forms which i dont want! Can there be anything more dynamic  ?

Comment: yes we can make this form in common to all pages, and specific class to the link and use javascript to submit the form on click on the link which have the class. So it will pass value as post. It works for me. I used this method for one of my project. You have to make little bit tricky on it. It will work dynamic

Comment: Okay let me check i will get back to you if I need any help :)